# What is the curl of a gradient crossed with a constant vector?

Tags: vector-analysis, curl

Let $a$ be any scalar and $\mathbf{B}$ be a constant vector. $\nabla \times \nabla a = 0$ and $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = 0$. But is $\nabla \times [(\nabla a) \times \mathbf{B}]=0$?

Comment: Have you had a go at trying to prove / disprove this?

Comment: Is $a$ a scalar function or just a constant scalar? The latter would trivialize this but it's not evident from what you've written.

Comment: JEdwards: Yes, I have tried unsuccessfully, either way.

Comment: Semiclassical: As I said, *a* is **any** scalar function. Hence, it is not necessarily constant.